# add uiview as subview to MKmapview using MKMapPoint

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to add uiview in  MKMapPoint,The code i have tried is given below but it's doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 {
     CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.myMapView];

     CLLocationCoordinate2D tapPoint = [self.myMapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.view];

     MKMapPoint myMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tapPoint);

     UIView *mymapview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myMapPoint.x, myMapPoint.y, 20, 20)];

     mymapview.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

     [self.view addSubview:mymapview];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourmapview addSubview: mymapview];
```

Add your mymapview on the map view like the above.

Comment: as he said: dont add it to self.view but on yourmapview